# Playbook to run the ansible task after successful execution of before ansible task in windows

Tags: ansible

I'm executing the below YAML(ansible) file using Jenkins.
I want to execute task2 only after the successful execution of task1, My YAML file is as below.
How do I add the dependency for this?
Requesting help on this

For example: application.yml

```
-name: task1
 win_command: "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\FRAMEWORK\V3.9.3013\MSBuild.exe" "E:\ApplicationFolder\App.xml" -target:Execute /p:ApplicationName="appname"
 register: executeapp1
 tags:
   - execute-app1

-name: task2
 win_command: "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\FRAMEWORK\V3.9.3013\MSBuild.exe" "E:\ApplicationFolder\App.xml" -target:Execute /p:ApplicationName="appname1"
 register: executeapp2
 tags:
   - execute-app2
```

Comment: It's built in.  Ansible will not continue working on a host after a task fails on that host.  With WinDoze, however, I have found that `win_command` often does not set the `failed` flag properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want the flow to continue even if task1 failed, you can use `ignore_errors` (bad practice) or `failed_when` to tell ansible not to fail task1 even if the command failed. and you can then tell if the command failed based on `executeapp1.rc` (which would be 0 if the command succeeded), `executeapp1.stdout` and `executeapp1.stderr`

the way Ansible works, Ansible will fail the host if task1 fails (and the entire flow if all hosts failed), so there's nothing specific you need to do. if you have a more complex situation, where you want the flow to continue even after a failure (and for task2 to run only if task1 executed successfully), you can do it with a combination of `failed_when` on task1 and `when` on task2. avoid using `ignore_errors`, it is a dangerous practice.

`failed_when` tells Ansible what to consider a failure, even if the command failed. for example, you can write:

```
failed_when:
  - executeapp1.rc != 0
  - rc.stderr != 'output you consider a failure'
```

this will cause task1 to fail only if the command failed with a specific error message (which is different than what you stated). you can then also use `executeapp1` to decide on task2, with:

```
when:
  - executeapp1.rc == 0
```

Comment: Is this way correct in case if we are having 3 to 4 tasks in one yaml
`-name: task3
      win_command: "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\FRAMEWORK\V3.9.3013\MSBuild.exe" "E:\ApplicationFolder\App.xml" -target:Execute /p:ApplicationName="appname1"
     register: executeapp2
     failed_when:
        - executeapp3.rc != 0
     when:
          - executeapp2.rc == 0
     tags:
        - execute-app`

Comment: the formatting makes it hard to read, but it looks like your `when` and `failed_when` are reversed